# While changing one state in React both states are getting changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, use-state

I am trying to change one state but while doing that somehow my other state is also getting changed and I can't find the problem in this what should I do?
here is my code :

```
import React, {useState } from 'react'


 //style = {{margin : '50px', minWidth : '1200px' , minHeight : '500px'}
 const Container = ()=>{
const [arr , setArray] = useState([])
const [steps , setSteps] = useState([[]]);


const createArray = () =>{
    let array = []
        let i = 0;
        while (i <60){
          let number =  Math.random()*100;
            array.push(number);
            i++;
        }
         return array;
}
const BubbleSort = (array) =>{
    let funarray = new Array();
    funarray = array ;
    for (let i = 0 ; i < funarray.length-1 ; i++){
        for(let j = 0 ; j < funarray.length-1 ; j++){
            if(funarray[j]>funarray[j+1]){
                [funarray[j],funarray[j+1]] = [funarray[j+1],funarray[j]]
                setSteps([...steps,funarray]);
            }
        }
    }
}
    
  const handleCreateNewData = ()=>{
   let newarr = createArray();

    setArray([...newarr]);

}
const handleBubbleSort = ()=>{
    BubbleSort(arr);
}


return(
    <div className="container "  style = {{margin : '50px ', minWidth : '1200px' , minHeight : '500px'}}>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col s2 " style = {{margin : '20px' , padding : '20px'}}>
            <div className="row" ><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn green" onClick = {handleCreateNewData}>Create New Array</a></div>
            <div className="row"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn black" onClick = {handleBubbleSort}>BubbleSort</a></div>
            <div className="row"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn black">button</a></div>
            <div className="row"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn black">button</a></div>
            <div className="row"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn black">button</a></div>
            <div className="row"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn black">button</a></div>

        </div>
        <div className="col s9 grey">
            <div style = {{minWidth : '1000px' , minHeight : '500px'}}>
               {arr.map((val , index)=>(
                   
                   
                   <div>
                   <div style = {{height : '1px'}}></div>
                    <div className="bar black" style = {{height : '7px' , width : val*8}}> </div>
                    <div style = {{height : '1px'}}></div>
                    </div>
                   
               )
               )
                   
               
               }
                
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default Container ;
```

I m trying to create an array of arrays in steps in which after each pass the new array will be saved but while doing that my arr is also changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistake is in the line:

```
funarray = array
```

of Bubblesort. Should work with:

```
funarray = [...array]
```

Otherwise you are modifying your original array, to which you are passing the reference.